# First k primes and unity

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Divide the first $k$ primes into $2$ groups, such that the difference of their products is one/unity, i.e. 
$$3-2=1;\;\;\;\;\;\;2*3-5=1;\;\;\;\;\;\; 3*5-2*7=1$$
After these three  $k=2$, $k=3$ and $k=4$, I couldn't find any other solutions. Do there exist another solutions ?

Comment: For $k\leq 25$ there are only solutions for $k\in\{2,3,4,7\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another example $k=7$ : $$5\times 11\times 13-2\times 3\times 7\times 17=1.$$

**Added** : Note that your $k$ has to satisfy $$p_1p_2\cdots p_k=\lfloor \sqrt{p_1p_2\cdots p_k}\rfloor\times(\lfloor \sqrt{p_1p_2\cdots p_k}\rfloor+1).$$

Comment: This must be the last solution ?

Comment: ,perhaps you can answer my other question ? : )

Comment: About modular equation involving odd primes

Comment: @TanakaC: I don't know if $k=7$ is the last, but see what I added.

Answer (score 0):

A quickly written perl program just testing @mathlove's condition with the 62 primes less than $300$ says there might be (it's only a neccessary condition) solutions for $k=2, 3, 4, 7, 22, 23, 24, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 36, 39, 43, 45, 47, 48, 49, 50, 59, 60, 61, 62$. (The program runs fast enough to provide even longer lists, but I think that is enough to see that it actually happens quite frequently. - Or I might have made a really silly programming error.) So it's not that valuable, but there are still many ways to divide the first e.g.  21 primes (to be exact $2^{21}=2097152$ ways) into two sets, so it does remove a lot of work.

If anyone wants to check (or just see) my code, it's at http://lego.3001.dk/pp.pl.

Comment: I think the two numbers with difference $1$ have to be $a=\lfloor \sqrt {p_1p_2\dots p_k}\rfloor$ and $b=a+1$ so just check those to see if they factorise as required.

Comment: You're right, they have to be, but factorisation is hard.

Comment: Factorisation isn't hard in this case, because you know what you need the factors to be, so you just test the first $k$ primes, and if they don't work, you haven't got a solution.

Comment: Implementing @MarkBennet's idea, my code has now ruled out that there are more solution for $k\leq 131$. Above that point, the product becomes too large for my script to handle.